# How to get selected check box value from a tree view in android

Tags: android, view, tree

I am creating android application that consists of a tree view.Here I am using the tree view downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/).I had a check boxes with the child views inside of a tree view.Here I need to get the selected check boxes values from the tree view can any one tell me how to get selected check box value from a tree view
This is my tree view:

```
package pl.polidea.treeview.demo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import pl.polidea.treeview.InMemoryTreeStateManager;
import pl.polidea.treeview.R;
import pl.polidea.treeview.TreeBuilder;
import pl.polidea.treeview.TreeNodeInfo;
import pl.polidea.treeview.TreeStateManager;
import pl.polidea.treeview.TreeViewList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Demo activity showing how the tree view can be used.
 * 
 */
public class TreeViewListDemo extends Activity {



    private enum TreeType implements Serializable {
        SIMPLE,
        FANCY
    }

    private final Set<Long> selected = new HashSet<Long>();

    private static final String TAG = TreeViewListDemo.class.getSimpleName();
    private TreeViewList treeView;

    public static final int[] DEMO_NODES = new int[] { 
                                                    0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2,2,2,//MR 1
                                                    0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2,2,2, //MR 2
                                                    0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2,    //MR 3 
                                                    0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2,    //MR 4
                                                    0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2,2,2,//MR 5
                                                    0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2,2,2,//MR 6
                                                    0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2,2,    //MR 7
                                                    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,    //UR
                                                    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,   //FUSE Bucket
                                                    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, //IR_LR         
                                                    0    

};
    private static final int LEVEL_NUMBER = 4;
    private TreeStateManager<Long> manager = null;
    private FancyColouredVariousSizesAdapter fancyAdapter;
    private SimpleStandardAdapter simpleAdapter;
    private TreeType treeType;
    private boolean collapsible;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        TreeType newTreeType = null;
        boolean newCollapsible;
        CheckBox box;
        treeView = (TreeViewList)findViewById(R.id.mainTreeView);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            manager = new InMemoryTreeStateManager<Long>();
            final TreeBuilder<Long> treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder<Long>(manager);
            for (int i = 0; i < DEMO_NODES.length; i++) {

                treeBuilder.sequentiallyAddNextNode((long) i, DEMO_NODES[i]);

            }
            Log.d(TAG, manager.toString());
            newTreeType = TreeType.SIMPLE;
            newCollapsible = true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            manager = (TreeStateManager<Long>) savedInstanceState
                    .getSerializable("treeManager");
            if (manager == null) {
                manager = new InMemoryTreeStateManager<Long>();
            }
            newTreeType = (TreeType) savedInstanceState
                    .getSerializable("treeType");
            if (newTreeType == null) {
                newTreeType = TreeType.SIMPLE;
            }
            newCollapsible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("collapsible");
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.main_demo);
        treeView = (TreeViewList) findViewById(R.id.mainTreeView);
        fancyAdapter = new FancyColouredVariousSizesAdapter(this, selected,manager, LEVEL_NUMBER);
        simpleAdapter = new SimpleStandardAdapter(this, selected, manager,LEVEL_NUMBER);
        setTreeAdapter(newTreeType);
        setCollapsible(newCollapsible);
        registerForContextMenu(treeView);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState) {
        outState.putSerializable("treeManager", manager);
        outState.putSerializable("treeType", treeType);
        outState.putBoolean("collapsible", this.collapsible);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    protected final void setTreeAdapter(final TreeType newTreeType) {
        this.treeType = newTreeType;
        switch (newTreeType) {
        case SIMPLE:
            treeView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
            break;
        case FANCY:
            treeView.setAdapter(fancyAdapter);
            break;
        default:
            treeView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
        }
    }

    protected final void setCollapsible(final boolean newCollapsible) {
        this.collapsible = newCollapsible;
        treeView.setCollapsible(this.collapsible);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        final MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
        final MenuItem collapsibleMenu = menu
                .findItem(R.id.collapsible_menu_item);
        if (collapsible) {
            collapsibleMenu.setTitle(R.string.collapsible_menu_disable);
            collapsibleMenu.setTitleCondensed(getResources().getString(
                    R.string.collapsible_condensed_disable));
        } else {
            collapsibleMenu.setTitle(R.string.collapsible_menu_enable);
            collapsibleMenu.setTitleCondensed(getResources().getString(
                    R.string.collapsible_condensed_enable));
        }
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.simple_menu_item) {
            setTreeAdapter(TreeType.SIMPLE);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.fancy_menu_item) {
            setTreeAdapter(TreeType.FANCY);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.collapsible_menu_item) {
            setCollapsible(!this.collapsible);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.expand_all_menu_item) {
            manager.expandEverythingBelow(null);
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.collapse_all_menu_item) {
            manager.collapseChildren(null);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(final ContextMenu menu, final View v,
            final ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        final AdapterContextMenuInfo adapterInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        final long id = adapterInfo.id;
        final TreeNodeInfo<Long> info = manager.getNodeInfo(id);
        final MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
        if (info.isWithChildren()) 
        {
            if (info.isExpanded()) 
            {
                menu.findItem(R.id.Test).setVisible(false);
                menu.findItem(R.id.Clear).setVisible(false);
            } 
        } 
             super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
        final AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        final long id = info.id;


        if(item.getItemId()==R.id.Test)
        {
            Toast.makeText(TreeViewListDemo.this, "SAMPLE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
            text.append("Selected Items : \n");



        }

        /*if (item.getItemId() == R.id.context_menu_collapse) {
            manager.collapseChildren(id);
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.context_menu_expand_all) {
            manager.expandEverythingBelow(id);
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.context_menu_expand_item) {
            manager.expandDirectChildren(id);
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.context_menu_delete) {
            manager.removeNodeRecursively(id);
            return true;
        } *///else {
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    //}
}
```

This is my adapter:

```
package pl.polidea.treeview.demo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Set;

import pl.polidea.treeview.AbstractTreeViewAdapter;
import pl.polidea.treeview.R;
import pl.polidea.treeview.TreeNodeInfo;
import pl.polidea.treeview.TreeStateManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This is a very simple adapter that provides very basic tree view with a
 * checkboxes and simple item description.
 * 
 */
public class SimpleStandardAdapter extends AbstractTreeViewAdapter<Long> 
{
    public TreeViewListDemo tree_view_list;

    private final Set<Long> selected;
    public int[] selected_items;
    CheckBox box;
    String Relay_Name[]={
                         "Measurment Relay Card 1","Relay Power 1","Relay 1  (K1)","Relay 2  (K2)","Relay 3  (K3)","Relay 4  (K4)","Relay 5  (K5)","Relay 6  (K6)","Relay 7  (K7)","Relay 8  (K8)",
                                                   "Relay Power 2","Relay 9  (K9)","Relay 10 (K10)","Relay 11 (K11)","Relay 12 (K12)","Relay 13 (K13)","Relay 14 (K14)","Relay 15 (K15)","Relay 16 (K16)",     
                         "Measurment Relay Card 2","Relay Power 1","Relay 1  (K1)","Relay 2  (K2)","Relay 3  (K3)","Relay 4  (K4)","Relay 5  (K5)","Relay 6  (K6)","Relay 7  (K7)","Relay 8  (K8)",
                                                   "Relay Power 2","Relay 9  (K9)","Relay 10 (K10)","Relay 11 (K11)","Relay 12 (K12)","Relay 13 (K13)","Relay 14 (K14)","Relay 15 (K15)","Relay 16 (K16)",
                         "Measurment Relay Card 3","Relay Power 1","Relay 1  (K1)","Relay 2  (K2)","Relay 3  (K3)","Relay 4  (K4)","Relay 5  (K5)","Relay 6  (K6)","Relay 7  (K7)","Relay 8  (K8)",
                         "Measurment Relay Card 4","Relay Power 1","Relay 1  (K1)","Relay 2  (K2)","Relay 3  (K3)","Relay 4  (K4)","Relay 5  (K5)","Relay 6  (K6)","Relay 7  (K7)","Relay 8  (K8)",
                         "Measurment Relay Card 5","Relay Power 1","Relay 1  (K1)","Relay 2  (K2)","Relay 3  (K3)","Relay 4  (K4)","Relay 5  (K5)","Relay 6  (K6)","Relay 7  (K7)","Relay 8  (K8)",
                                                   "Relay Power 2","Relay 9  (K9)","Relay 10 (K10)","Relay 11 (K11)","Relay 12 (K12)","Relay 13 (K13)","Relay 14 (K14)","Relay 15 (K15)","Relay 16 (K16)",
                         "Measurment Relay Card 6","Relay Power 1","Relay 1  (K1)","Relay 2  (K2)","Relay 3  (K3)","Relay 4  (K4)","Relay 5  (K5)","Relay 6  (K6)","Relay 7  (K7)","Relay 8  (K8)",
                                                   "Relay Power 2","Relay 9  (K9)","Relay 10 (K10)","Relay 11 (K11)","Relay 12 (K12)","Relay 13 (K13)","Relay 14 (K14)","Relay 15 (K15)","Relay 16 (K16)",                     
                         "Measurment Relay Card 7","Relay Power 1","Relay 1  (K1)","Relay 2  (K2)","Relay 3  (K3)","Relay 4  (K4)","Relay 5  (K5)","Relay 6  (K6)","Relay 7  (K7)","Relay 8  (K8)",                         
                         "Universal  Relay Card  ","Relay 1  (K1)","Relay 2  (K2)","Relay 3  (K3)","Relay 4  (K4)","Relay 5  (K5)","Relay 6  (K6)","Relay 7  (K7)","Relay 8  (K8)",                             
                         "Safety Fuse Relay Cards","Relay 1  (K1)","Relay 2  (K2)","Relay 3  (K3)","Relay 4  (K4)","Relay 5  (K5)","Relay 6  (K6)","Relay 7  (K7)","Relay 8  (K8)",                                 
                         "IR LR CARD             ","Relay 1  (K1)","Relay 2  (K2)","Relay 3  (K3)","Relay 4  (K4)", 
                         "Buzzer"    
                    };

    private final OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChange = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView,
                final boolean isChecked) {
            final Long id = (Long) buttonView.getTag();
           // changeSelected(isChecked, id);





        }

    };


    private void changeSelected(final boolean isChecked, final Long id) {
        if (isChecked) {
            selected.add(id);
        } else {
            selected.remove(id);
        }
    }

    public SimpleStandardAdapter(final TreeViewListDemo treeViewListDemo,
            final Set<Long> selected,
            final TreeStateManager<Long> treeStateManager,
            final int numberOfLevels) 
    {
        super(treeViewListDemo, treeStateManager, numberOfLevels);
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    private String getDescription(final long id) {
        final Integer[] hierarchy = getManager().getHierarchyDescription(id);
        return Relay_Name[(int) id];
    }

    @Override
    public View getNewChildView(final TreeNodeInfo<Long> treeNodeInfo) {
        final LinearLayout viewLayout = (LinearLayout) getActivity()
                .getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.demo_list_item, null);
        return updateView(viewLayout, treeNodeInfo);
    }

    @Override
    public LinearLayout updateView(final View view,
            final TreeNodeInfo<Long> treeNodeInfo) 
    {
        final LinearLayout viewLayout = (LinearLayout) view;
        final TextView descriptionView = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.demo_list_item_description);
        //final TextView levelView = (TextView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.demo_list_item_level);
        ;
        descriptionView.setText(getDescription(treeNodeInfo.getId()));

      //  levelView.setText(Integer.toString(treeNodeInfo.getLevel()));

        box = (CheckBox) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.demo_list_checkbox);

        //box.setTag(treeNodeInfo.getId());

        if (treeNodeInfo.isWithChildren()) 
        {
            box.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } 
        else 
        {
            box.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            box.setChecked(selected.contains(treeNodeInfo.getId()));
        }
        box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChange);

        return viewLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleItemClick(final View view, final Object id) {
        final Long longId = (Long) id;
        final TreeNodeInfo<Long> info = getManager().getNodeInfo(longId);
        if (info.isWithChildren()) {
            super.handleItemClick(view, id);
        } else {
            final ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view;
            final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) vg.findViewById(R.id.demo_list_checkbox);
            cb.performClick();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(final int position) {
        return getTreeId(position);
    }
}
```